# JSON Object: Getting Key from a value

Tags: javascript, json, object

Ok this is my simplified Object:

```json
{
  'aaa': {
    name: 'Profile one',
    created: 1587396315752,
    last_save: 1599936955429,
  },
  'bbb': {
    name: 'Profile two',
    created: 1594950234265,
    last_save: 1596064543536,
  },
  'ccc': {
    name: 'Profile three',
    created: 1586093327836,
    last_save: 1600022533585,
  }
}
```

I was aiming to have the user typing the name of the profile, `'Profile two'` for example, and return the corresponding profile id (`'bbb'`).
I tried in many ways but none of them worked as intended. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your question

Comment: _"I tried in many ways but none of them worked as intended"_ - Add the most promising attempt and explain what problems you have with it, any errors you encountered and what you've tried to fix them (a `for...in...` loop should be enough to solve this one).

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) as:

```js
const data = { 'aaa': { name: 'Profile one', created: 1587396315752, last_save: 1599936955429, }, 'bbb': { name: 'Profile two', created: 1594950234265, last_save: 1596064543536, }, 'ccc': { name: 'Profile three', created: 1586093327836, last_save: 1600022533585, } };

const search = 'Profile two';
const result = Object.entries(data)
                     .find(([k,v]) => v.name === search)[0];

console.log(result);
```

See from the documentations:

> The `Object.entries()` method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable string-keyed property [key, value] pairs, in the same order as that provided by a for...in loop

> The `find()` method returns the value of the first element in the provided array that satisfies the provided testing function.

Answer (score 0):

You can find it using `Object.entries()` and `find()`:

```js
let profiles = {
  'aaa': {
    name: 'Profile one',
    created: 1587396315752,
    last_save: 1599936955429,
  },
  'bbb': {
    name: 'Profile two',
    created: 1594950234265,
    last_save: 1596064543536,
  },
  'ccc': {
    name: 'Profile three',
    created: 1586093327836,
    last_save: 1600022533585,
  }
};

let id = Object.entries(profiles).find(e => e[1].name === 'Profile two')[0];
console.log(id);
```